# WebScrape placar previdência

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

Precisava extrair as informações desse site para um arquivo excel, quais deputados votam a favor, contra, as abstenções, enfim. É um exc de webscrape, mas como entendo de html estou com dificuldades para entender os nodes.
Já tentei `read_html`, `readHTMLTable`, `readLines`, mas nenhum desses funcionou como desejado.

Algum de vcs tem alguma sugestão?

http://infograficos.estadao.com.br/especiais/placar/votacao/economia/?id=GLwN7vXR3W

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando os pacotes `stringr` e `rvest` a questão pode ser solucionada assim:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
url <- 'http://infograficos.estadao.com.br/especiais/placar/votacao/economia/?id=GLwN7vXR3W'

resp <- read_html(url)
```

Já que vamos pegar textos várias vezes, convém escrever uma função:

```
pega_texto <- function (css) {
  resp %>% html_nodes(css) %>% html_text()
}

posicoes <- pega_texto('h3') %>% str_extract('[A-Z].+')

quantidades <- pega_texto('h3') %>% str_extract('[0-9]+') %>% as.numeric()

posicao <- mapply(rep, x =  posicoes, each = quantidades) %>% 
  unlist()

partido <- pega_texto('.p-org')
nome <- pega_texto('.p-name') %>% 
  .[. != "Placar da Previdência (intenção do voto)"]
regiao <- pega_texto('.p-region')

dados <- data.frame(partido, nome, regiao, posicao)

head(dados)

  partido           nome regiao posicao
1      PP Adail Carneiro     CE A favor
2    PMDB  Alberto Filho     MA A favor
3     PPS   Alex Manente     SP A favor
4    PMDB Altineu Côrtes     RJ A favor
5      PP    André Abdon     AP A favor
6     PSD André de Paula     PE A favor

openxlsx::write.xlsx(dados, "arquivo.xlsx)
```

**EDITADO**

Tinha esquecido de comentar sobre a exportação para Excel. Recomendo usar o pacote `openxlsx` porque ele usa C++ para acessar o Excel. O pacote `xlsx` usa Java e é comum ocorrer problemas de incompatibilidade com o Java (32-bit X 64-bit).

Comment: mto bom, os nodes que vc pegou vem do próprio site?

Comment: Sim. O [CSS gadget selector](http://selectorgadget.com/) ajuda na tarefa de encontrá-los.

Answer (score 3):

Para importar os dados sobre o Placar da Previdência, infográfico do site do Estadão e exportar para Excel, utilize o código abaixo.

Caso não tenha instalado os pacotes 'XML', 'xlsx' e 'stringr', execute a primeira linha.

```
install.packages(c('XML', 'xlsx', 'stringr'))


library(XML)
library(stringr)
library(xlsx)

url <- 'http://infograficos.estadao.com.br/especiais/placar/votacao/economia/?id=GLwN7vXR3W'
paginavoto <- htmlParse(url)

tipo <- xpathSApply(paginavoto, "//section//h3", fun = xmlValue)
deputados <- data.frame(nome = character(), 
                    partido = character(), 
                    voto = character())

for(i in 1:length(tipo)){
  if(as.numeric(str_extract(tipo[i], '\\d+')) != 0){

    pDep <- paste0("//section[",i ,"]//span[@class='p-name']")
    pPart <- paste0("//section[",i ,"]//span[@class='p-org']")
    deputado <- data.frame(nome = xpathSApply(paginavoto, pDep, fun = xmlValue),
                   partido = xpathSApply(paginavoto, pPart, fun = xmlValue),
                   voto = trimws(str_extract(tipo[i], '\\D+')))
    deputados <- rbind(deputados, deputado)
  }
}

write.xlsx(deputados, "deputados.xlsx")
```